# SQL multiple Updates Queries One after the other

Tags: mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

I am running into an error on the syntax on the code below, if I execute this on the app (wordpress) I get an error message, a single Update query on its own works fine, but I need to update several ID's with unique values at once.

One thing to say is if I run this in my Database managers SQL COMMAND it works fine, I am assuming it is taking each query in turn. Any help would be great!

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta 
SET    meta_value = "299" 
WHERE  meta_key = '_regular_price' 
       AND post_id = '2126'; 

UPDATE wp_postmeta 
SET    meta_value = "199" 
WHERE  meta_key = '_sale_price' 
       AND post_id = '2126';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why multiple updates are not working from Wordpress.  They should, I think, and as you have seen, there is nothing wrong with doing this from MySQL.  If you really needed a single update, you could do this:

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta
SET meta_value = CASE WHEN meta_key = '_regular_price'
                      THEN '299'
                      WHEN meta_key = '_sale_price'
                      THEN '199' END
WHERE
    meta_key IN ('_regular_price', '_sale_price') AND
    post_id = '2126';
```

Comment: yeah, I have seen that method too, the issue is that I have multiple post_id to update too. I tried your code - it works perfect for a single row. So it could be expanded upon - seems like I will just need to use the SQL Command. Not a major issue - could be to do with the plugin I am using. It may not allow multiple query triggered, as it would slow the admin down.